# VueJS - Is there a way to conditionally apply a transition?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

What I would like to do is create an alert box component with a custom reveal transition that is optional, something like this (edited for brevity):

```
<template>
    <transition v-if="withTransition">
        <b-alert v-bind="this.$attrs" />
    </transition>
</template>
```

I will have a `withTransition` prop that ideally will conditionally render only the transition effect, and not affect the rendering of the alert box.

`v-if` and `v-show` won't work because those properties would show and hide the alert component as well. Plus, AFAIK `<transition>` does not render as a DOM element, so I'm not sure how that could be conditionally rendered, if at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: New to vue.js so not sure if below suggestion will work. how about applying css class dynamically with the condition and keep transition effect in css class?

Comment: Using CSS class with transitions just negates the power of Vue. If you're using Vue... then use Vue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [dynamic transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Dynamic-Transitions) and bind to a transition name (using a computed property) that does nothing when you want the effect disabled.

For example...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ withTransition: true, show: false }),
  computed: {
    computedTransition () {
      return this.withTransition && 'fade'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.alert {
  background-color: #f99;
  border: 1px solid #f66;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label>
      With transition:
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="withTransition"/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p><button type="button" @click="show = !show">Toggle alert</button></p>
  <transition :name="computedTransition">
    <p class="alert" v-if="show">Something happened</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

### **Use an inline ternary condition**

If you just need to quickly check against a variable, this is an option:

```
<transition :name="someVariable == 'someValue' ? 'myTransitionA' : 'myTransitionB'">
```

`someVariable` could be anything (prop, data, computed, method...).

Set a transition name (e.g.`'myTransitionB'`) to just an empty string `''` if you wanted no transition at all for a particular condition.

I use this technique to toggle transitions based on different UI contexts (e.g. mobile vs desktop). For example, I want control bars to slide in-and-out in mobile, but I want them to be static on desktop.